# Read memory values of a process in windows using nodejs

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, memory, process

**Summary**:

I was wondering if it is possible to read memory values of a process ( in **Windows** ) using **nodejs**.

I have some C++ code that does just that. For *some reasons*, I want to do that using nodejs.

---

**Q1:** Is it possible to create an addon for the C++ code to be used with nodejs ?

**Q2:** Is it possible to extract the data from C++ asynchronously and use them in my nodejs app ?

**Q3:** Can I rewrite the program using Javascript ( nodejs and modules ) ?

Each question, if possible, is considered a solution to my problem.
If you choose to answer 1 or more of them, please

- Give me a synopsis of the process
- Point me to the right directions ( for example, Documentations, Guides, SO answers etc.. )

> Any answer, is a good answer to a "difficult", demanding question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and well documented in the [Node.js API Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). There is also a official [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples) with some examples. I wouldn't consider this a proper answer, so that's why I decided to just write a comment.

Comment: Thank you. Care to elaborate your answer a bit more ? Maybe give me a summary of the process so that i can accept it as an answer

Comment: To be honest, I haven't done anything with C++ addons for a long time and I'd have to read the docs again myself. So you're probably better off just looking at the examples. It's really not that hard once you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is likely possible, but it really depends upon what memory values you're trying to read and whether the OS allows an external process to read them.

nodejs itself does not have code to generically read memory from another process so you will need to write and run your own native code.  To run native code from nodejs, you will need to either write a nodejs module using the Nodejs API documentation in order to call native code directly from within nodejs or you can write a standalone executable in native code and execute that using the `child_process module` and have it return some data to you.  Either option will work fine assuming you have the ability in your own native code to read the desired memory and are not blocked by process boundaries in the OS.

> Q1: Is it possible to create an addon for the C++ code to be used with
>   nodejs ?

Yes, this is well documented for nodejs here in the [nodejs API documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

> Q2: Is it possible to extract the data from C++ asynchronously and use
>   them in my nodejs app ?

If you want the operation to be asynchronous, then you will have to execute your native code asynchronously (either in an OS thread or in another process) and communicate back the result via some callback.  Many of nodejs' own functions are built this way.

> Q3: Can I rewrite the program using Javascript ( nodejs and modules )
>   ?

You can't read memory values from an external process entirely from nodejs (since nodejs does not have that capability built-in).  You will need some of your own native code that can be either an addon or an external process that you execute from node.js.

---

Since you already have native C++ code that does what you want, it sounds like the simplest scheme may be to just wrap that code into it's own C++ app and have it communicate back the results either via `stdout` or by writing to a passed in filename or something like that.  Then, you can just use the `child_process` module in node.js to execute your C++ app and retrieve the results it provides.  By nature of it executing in another process and using the appropriate child_process methods you can retrieve the result asynchronously.  The [child_process module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) contains multiple examples for how to use its various methods.

Comment: I am so glad you answered each and every part of my question! Also, very beautifully written and elaborated. The last part of your answer is a solution to exactly what I have in mind as a problem. Thank you and Happy Christmas holidays ( if you celebrate it ).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/node-memory-process-scanner) is a rudimentary addon for reading the process of another window.